# Can You "Tag" a file in Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net, file, file-location

In Vb.Net is there any way to "tag" a file so if I was to change its location my program could still find it, without the user having to search for it? 
I am using:

> If Not System.IO.File.Exists(C:\Location\Folder\FileName.txt) Then System.IO.File.Create(C:\Location\Folder\FileName.txt)

Answer (score 0):

If it is the program that is changing the location of the file, then you could store the current location in the registry, in the app's config file, in a database, or in a plain text file in a known directory near the application.

I generally store this information in the registry or a database (assuming the application uses one) since this will survive uninstall and reinstall events.